How to trigger Google web authentication from a custom button
I'm using the new Google sign in method as described in the Sign In with Google for Web Documentation. It is working fine, but I would like to change it so that my very own button is trggering the popup and not use the Google <div id="buttonDiv"></div>. I've tried to achieve this by calling google.accounts.id.prompt(); but that does trigger the One Tap dialog instead of the regular popup where the user can select an account.
How can I trigger the regular popup from my own button? Which function should I call?
EDIT Just found this workaround: https://medium.com/@leonardosalles/a-guide-to-custom-google-sign-in-button-e7b02c2c5e4f - not sure how sustainable that is though.
